# Why doesn't setTimeout work as callback?

Tags: jquery, callback, settimeout

Basically, I'm trying to fade in `#container_swap` over `#container`, wait two seconds, then swap the background of `#container` and finally fade `#container_swap` out.

```
function swapBg(){
    $('#container').css('background-image',newBg)
    $('#container_swap').hide();
}
$(
    function(){
        $('#container_swap')
            .css('background-image',newBg)
            .fadeIn(2000)
        ,setTimeout(swapBg(), 2000)
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `swapBg` and passing its result to `setTimeout`. You want to pass the function instead:

```
setTimeout(swapBg, 2000)
```